# Modern times Embrace with an unwilling sire

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

One of the characters I'm dealing with currently is a student of medicine who's come up with a rather elaborate scheme for his Embrace, gathered from high-generation vampires who couldn't care less about the Masquerade. (Their fates, as well as the standing of such a Tradition-violating new Kindred, lie not within the question's scope.)

One of the rules about the Embrace states that a direct vitae flow must happen between sire and childe. So, to prevent any actual dues owed to the sire, he has decided to kidnap an unwilling high-generation vampire, and via an unholy contraption of IV bags and an assistant's help, drain himself of blood and then have the staked would-be sire bled into his mouth enough to fill the Vitae quota for an Embrace. Then feast on his own blood to prevent frenzy.

Assuming that a vampire can be captured by a capable kine via the virtue of being a dumb vampire, this poses several risks.

The big question being **"Would the Embrace happen?"**, can already get a weak "yes" from the canon via the example of Dracula and Lambach Ruthven
 as to whether a forced Embrace is possible, yet from what I know of it, it happened more or less traditionally, while this spin on it takes away a lot of the "safety" of the traditional way to force an Embrace from an unworthy vampire.

This is assuming the V20 version of the rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Mechanically, there's no reason it *shouldn't* work.

There hasn't been an exhaustive description of the process and factors that affect it, but the core ones we know about should be covered by this setup. The sire is there, the subject is drained of all their blood and dies, the vitae is immediately fed to the subject, and since the sire is high generation there isn't much (known) risk of failure.

The risks in the process would lie outside that moment of Embrace, and would be considerable, but those are not in scope for the question.

If you're interested in more detail on those risks, and how they might be dealt with, you might want to check out *Ghouls and Revenants* (V20) and/or *Ghouls: Fatal Addiction* (Revised). If my memory serves correctly, these have sections on a group called the Unmastered that has developed techniques that would be very useful to your ambitious, risk-tolerant med student.

Answer (score 3):

Mechanically, everything up until the frenzy sounds plausible.  The transfer of vitae in the manner you describe hasn't been exactly defined for the purpose of creating fun scenarios such as yours.

Upon transformation into a vampire, the character would frenzy due to having less than a single blood point.  Normally, the sire will provide their own blood or a victim to feed off of.  Blood bags would be a less-favored source of blood if something warm is nearby, such as the assistant.

Setting up the scenario is very unlikely, however, unless you're hand-waving all that to allow it to be established as a character's backstory.  It is unlikely for the following reasons:

1. The human needs to fully understand the Embrace.  There is a lot of false information out there about how the embrace happens and the human would need to sift out truth from fiction.  Likely, they'd need access to kindred society to learn the truth, if not from a reliable second-hand source.
2. The human needs to identify a vampire without becoming its prey.  The exact setting of your story would dictate this difficulty.
3. The human needs to capture the vampire.  Disciplines like Auspex and Presence would make it less likely for the human to out-talk the vampire to get them into the situation to start.  Disciplines like Celerity and Potence make it less likely for the human to out-power the vampire and restrain him long enough to stake.  A few dots Fortitude would make it neigh impossible for a human to stake them before the vampire heals and flees/kills them.  Dominate would stop any aggressor in their tracks.

These considerations in mind, though, would create for a lot of storytelling hooks for the campaign.

Comment: The question specifies that the student already knows some rogue vampires and they've come up with this plan together.  Given that, it begins to look a lot more plausible.  I take it that the idea is that he doesn't want to be Embraced by one of them because then he'll be bonded to them, and the plan is that the vampires will help him to kidnap a low-ranking vampire who they don't like, perform the grisly experiment and then do for the unwilling sire.  Hopefully the assistant is also one of the vampires, otherwise, as you say, they may be in trouble!